# Ignore invalid item when decoding list

Tags: elm

is it possible to ignore invalid items when decoding the list?
example: I have a Model

```
type Type
    = A
    | B

type alias Section =
    { sectionType : Type
    , index : Int
    }


getTypeFromString : String -> Maybe Type
getTypeFromString input =
    case input of
        “a” ->
            Just A

        “b” ->
            Just B

        _ ->
            Nothing

decodeType : Decoder Type
decodeType =
    Decode.string
        |> Decode.andThen
            (\str ->
                case getTypeFromString str of
                    Just sectionType ->
                        Decode.succeed sectionType

                    Nothing ->
                        Decode.fail <| ("Unknown type" ++ str)
            )


decodeSection : Decoder Section
decodeSection =
    Decode.map2 Section
        (Decode.field "type" decodeType)
        (Decode.field "index" Decode.int)
```

if I decode the JSON

```
{
  "sections": [{type: "A", index: 1}, {type: "invalid-type", index: 2}]
}
```

I expect my sections = [ {type = A, index= 1} ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comment by Quan Vo about one of many fields could be invalid, using `Decode.oneOf` might be a better fit.

You write the decoders for each field. If any field is illegal, the `Section` decoder fails and in `oneOf`, `Nothing` is returned.

(Here I am also using `Json.Decode.Pipeline` from NoRedInk).

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline exposing (required)


type Type
    = A
    | B


type alias Section =
    { sectionType : Type
    , index : Int
    }


getTypeFromString : String -> Maybe Type
getTypeFromString input =
    case input |> String.toLower of
        "a" ->
            Just A

        "b" ->
            Just B

        _ ->
            Nothing


decodeType : Decoder Type
decodeType =
    Decode.string
        |> Decode.andThen
            (\str ->
                case getTypeFromString str of
                    Just sectionType ->
                        Decode.succeed sectionType

                    Nothing ->
                        Decode.fail <| ("Unknown type" ++ str)
            )


decodeSection : Decoder Section
decodeSection =
    Decode.succeed Section
        |> required "type" decodeType
        |> required "index" Decode.int

-- Either we succeed in decoding a Section or fail on some field.
decodeMaybeSection : Decoder (Maybe Section)
decodeMaybeSection =
    Decode.oneOf
        [ decodeSection |> Decode.map Just
        , Decode.succeed Nothing
        ]


decodeSections : Decoder (List Section)
decodeSections =
    Decode.list decodeMaybeSection
        |> Decode.map (List.filterMap identity)
```

Answer (score 6):

Generally the way you can deal with these is by decoding it to an Elm type that expresses the options, and then post processing with a `map`.

So for instance in your example, I would go for something like this:

```
decodeMaybeType : Decoder (Maybe Type)
decodeMaybeType =
    Decode.string
        |> Decode.map getTypeFromString 


decodeMaybeSection : Decoder (Maybe Section)
decodeMaybeSection =
    Decode.map2 (\maybeType index -> Maybe.map (\t -> Section t index) maybeType)
        (Decode.field "type" decodeMaybeType)
        (Decode.field "index" Decode.int)


decodeSections : Decoder (List Section)
decodeSections =
    Decode.list decodeMaybeSection
       |> Decode.map (List.filterMap identity)
```

NB: `List.filterMap identity` is a `List (Maybe a) -> List a`, it filters out the `Nothing` and gets rid of the `Maybe`s in one go.

Comment: is there any way more generic? in my example, there are only 2 fields, how about if the type has 10 fields, and any field can be invalid, we can not define Maybe for all the fields, right?